# How to save a CSV file to a variable with a foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Basically, I am loading a CSV file via a HTML upload form, then saving it into PHP.
I need to create a foreach loop to somehow print out the file line by line.

I am not to sure how to do this since I have honestly never designed a PHP foreach loop before.

This is the code that is capturing and saving the multidimensional array from the CSV file

```
$csv_array = array(array());
$file = fopen($_FILES['upload_csv']['tmp_name'], 'r');
if($file)
{
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) 
    {
        $csv_array[] = array_combine(range(1, count($line)), array_values($line));
    }

    fclose($file);
}
```

This is my current foreach loop which is not working well at all which I grabbed and slightly changed from one of my other functions.

```
$all_questions;
if(!empty($csv_array)) 
{
    foreach($csv_array as $question) 
    {
        $all_questions = $all_questions . implode(',',$question) . "\n";
    }
}
```

So in conclusion, I need my foreach loop to go through my multidimensional array to save it as one big string. If my CSV file is like this:

```
question1,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4
question2,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4
question3,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4
```

I need it saved into a variable in the exact same format. I need to also keep my multidimensional array since I need it for other reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up somehow making it myself. Had to skip the first element, so that explains the array_slice.

```
foreach (array_slice($csv_array,1) as $row) 
{
    $all_questions = $all_questions . $row[1] . ",";
    $all_questions = $all_questions . $row[2] . ",";
    $all_questions = $all_questions . $row[3] . ",";
    $all_questions = $all_questions . $row[4] . ",";
    $all_questions = $all_questions . $row[5];
    $all_questions = $all_questions . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Would be easier to use `join()`. A _trigger_ should be reading many lines that are almost the same.